# JQuery Selectmenu - getting selected value after selectmenu items are added on scriptside

Tags: jquery, postback, selectedvalue

I have a dropdownlist and adding options to it using json & jquery.

My first problem was "enableValidation" state, I solved that by adding enable validation = false on top of the page, which I'm not proud.

My second problem is, when I do some postback, the generated & selected option is not set on "selectedvalue" property, it's just an empty string, when it's supposed to be "7".

Can somebody help?

Comment: Show us some code. Or better, make a little example on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first use a hidden variable and than store selectedvalue to  the user input
`<input type="hidden" name="Iname" id="Iid" />`

use the `Request.QueryString["Iname"].Value` or `Iid.Value` to retrieve the value in Postback function.

Hops its helps

Comment: thanks a lot, yours is the fastest solution I got. I did something like that, too.

I put the eventvalidation on top of the page again, with "true". and removed "runat=server" attribute from the dropdown. Then I put the value on html hidden server control and got the value from it.

Thanks for your answer.